# Automating access 2003 application

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have an access application (VBA) ( access 2003 ) , which generates 4 different text file based on its database at specific path on pressing of 4 respective different buttons.

But this is something manual , which i do everyday for the file generation.

Im in need of its automation.For example my file should get automatically generate at any specific time.

One of the button's event procedure is menitoned below :

I tried doing with help of VB script , but this is giving error .

"Provider cannot be found.May not be properly installed "

```
 Set objAccess = CreateObject("Access.Application") 
 Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
 strConnect = "Provider=Microsoft.JETs.OLEDB.12.0;
 Data Source=E:\Project\test.mdb"
 conn.Open strConnect


 test()

function test()
objAccess.DoCmd.Hourglass True
objAccess.DoCmd.SetWarnings False
objAccess.DoCmd.RunSQL ("INSERT INTO Table1 ( name, FileName, [DateTime] ) SELECT Environ(""UserName"") AS name, ""test.mdb Generate ABCD File"" AS FileName, Format(Now(),""yyyyMMddhhmmss"") AS [DateTime];")
objAccess.DoCmd.OpenQuery ("qry_ABCD")
objAccess.DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, "qry_ABCD_Formatted Export Specification", "qry_ABCD_Formatted", "E:\Ouputs\" & Format(Now(), "yyyymmdd") & ".txt", False
objAccess.DoCmd.SetWarnings True
objAccess.DoCmd.Hourglass False
End function
```

I dnt know how to resolve this issue. Or is there any other better way to resolve this.

Comment: Should it be `JET` not `JETs`? http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175866(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to setup or create some connection string in your script. Once you opened Access, then you have use of all tables in that application. And in fact in your example you create a conneciton object, but it not really required.

So, lets assume your VBA code to run is this:

```
Sub MyExport()

  Dim strSQL     As String
  strSQL = "INSERT INTO Table1 ( name, FileName, [DateTime] ) " & _
           "SELECT Environ(""UserName"") AS name, ""test.mdb Generate ABCD File"" AS FileName, " & _
           "Format(Now(),""yyyyMMddhhmmss"") AS [DateTime];"

  CurrentDb.Execute strSQL

  DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, "qry_ABCD_Formatted Export Specification", _
                     "qry_ABCD_Formatted", _
                     "E:\Ouputs\" & Format(Now(), "yyyymmdd") & ".txt", _
                     False

End Sub
```

The above code is assumed to be saved as a sub (not a function) in a STANDARD MS Access VBA code module.

Now, your VBS scrip can call the above code like this:
    dim accessApp
     set accessApp = createObject("Access.Application")
     accessApp.OpenCurrentDataBase("C:\some path name\someMdb.accDB")

```
 accessApp.Run "MyExport"
 accessApp.Quit
```

So it now a simple matter to run the above VBS script. And such a script should also just run fine via the windows task scheduler. As above shows there is LITTLE need to put the SQL and code in the VBS script. You BEST get the sub working in VBA and MAKE SURE it works. Test it many times, and THEN and ONLY then do you create the VBS cript to call that sub. So FIRST get the routine working, and get it working WITHOTU any prompts etc. You can call and test the VBA sub by placing your cursor in the VBA editor in that routine, and then hit F5 to run the sub. Once you get it working the way you want, then you use the above second VBS (not VBA script to call + run that working sub that you are NOW 100% SURE it works and runs correctly)